# vncserver creating display as :<Displaynumber> instead of hostname:<Displaynumber>

Tags: solaris, vnc, vnc-server

When I run `vncserver` command it will create session with display as `:1` ,and in the terminal when we check the display variable, it is set as `DISPLAY=:1`, Is it possible to create a vnc session with display variable set as `DISPLAY=hostname:1`, I know to change the display variable by using `export` or `setenv` command depending on the shell, But if I change the display variable manually to `hostname:1` , `xhost` command doesn't work as the vnc session is originally created for `:1` only,

Am not sure why this behavior or is this the default behavior?

Am using Solaris 11.4 OS

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding how X Windows `DISPLAY` environment variables work.

Per [the X.org documentation](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.0/doc/X.7.html#sect4) (bolding mine):

> From the user's perspective, every X server has a display name of the
> form:
>
> ```
> hostname:displaynumber.screennumber
> ```
>
> This information is used by the application to determine how it should
> connect to the server and which screen it should use by default (on
> displays with multiple monitors):
>
> *hostname*
>
> The hostname specifies the name of the machine to which the display is
> physically connected. **If the hostname is not given, the most efficient
> way of communicating to a server on the same machine will be used**.
>
> *displaynumber*
>
> The phrase "display" is usually used to refer to collection of
> monitors that share a common keyboard and pointer (mouse, tablet,
> etc.). Most workstations tend to only have one keyboard, and
> therefore, only one display. Larger, multi-user systems, however,
> frequently have several displays so that more than one person can be
> doing graphics work at once. To avoid confusion, each display on a
> machine is assigned a display number (beginning at 0) when the X
> server for that display is started. The display number must always be
> given in a display name.
>
> *screennumber*
>
> Some displays share a single keyboard and pointer among two or more
> monitors. Since each monitor has its own set of windows, each screen
> is assigned a screen number (beginning at 0) when the X server for
> that display is started. If the screen number is not given, screen 0
> will be used.
>
> On POSIX systems, the default display name is stored in your DISPLAY
> environment variable. This variable is set automatically by the xterm
> terminal emulator. However, when you log into another machine on a
> network, you will need to set DISPLAY by hand to point to your
> display. For example, ...

From the X server process, **there is no `hostname` part of a display name** - the server is running on the system it's running on.

So setting an X server to run on `hostname:1` is no different than setting it to run on `:1`.

For X Windows client programs, though, the `hostname` part of a `DISPLAY` environment variable denotes the system where the display they need to connect to is running.  In other words, the connect becomes a *network* connection.

When your `xterm` process is started locally, it connects to the *local* X server process by default, denoted with `:1` (or `:0` or `:0.0` or `:2.0`...).  Setting `DISPLAY=hostname:1` means the X client process will try to perform a network connection to the `:1` display, running on the `hostname` system.  **And if the X server process isn't configured to listen for network connections in addition to local connections, or if there's a firewall in the way, that client process will fail to connect to `hostname:1`**.

So just using the `xhost` command to enable remote access won't work if the X server isn't configure to allow such access.

For the `:1` display, if your X server *is* configured to allow remote access, running `netstat -an | grep 6001` will produce output something like this:

```
*:6001       *      *     0     0 256000     * LISTEN
```

If you do not see any process with `LISTEN` on port 6001, the X server for your `:1` display is not configured to accept remote connections.